# i am using esp32 espressif id for development and having this problem when i choose com port selection

Tags: javascript, python, c++, node.js, visual-studio-code

Command failed: "C:\Users\DELL.espressif\python_env\idf4.4_py3.8_env\Scripts\python.exe" -m pip install --user virtualenv
ERROR: Can not perform a '--user' install. User site-packages are not visible in this virtualenv.
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.3.3; however, version 22.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\DELL.espressif\python_env\idf4.4_py3.8_env\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: "If this command returns Can not perform a '--user' install. User site-packages are not visible in this virtualenv. then you are already in a Python virtual environment." from [here](https://pycbc.org/pycbc/latest/html/install_virtualenv.html#install-virtualenv)

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `--user`:

```
python -m pip install virtualenv
```

**--user**

```
Install to the Python user install directory for your platform. Typically ~/.local/, or %APPDATA%\Python on Windows. (See the Python documentation for site.USER_BASE for fulldetails.)
```

[official docs](https://pycbc.org/pycbc/latest/html/install_virtualenv.html#install-virtualenv):

> If this command returns **Can not perform a '--user' install. User**
> **site-packages are not visible in this virtualenv.** then you are already
> in a Python virtual environment. You will need to deactivate this
> environment or contact your system administrator to install virtualenv
> for you in this environment.